# FusedLocationProviderClient returns inaccurate locations

Tags: android, google-api, location, android-location, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am using Google's fusedlocationproviderclient to track location of user in real time on android using  a foreground service.
I have noticed some times fusedlocationproviderclient returns same locations multiple times in a row.
As of now I am observing, sometimes fusedlocationproviderclient  return very inaccurate location **(Around 700m)**.

Earlier I used to track location using Location_Services but moved to fusedlocationproviderclient in order to reduce battery consumption.
I have set fusedlocationproviderclient priority to High Accuracy.
I have set minDisplacement to 100m.

This is my location object

```
private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(100);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

I am expecting it should return accurate locations.
As I display tracked locations onto a static map die to incorrect location a straight line appears in map.

Comment: I am just starting down this path with FusedLocationProviderClient. But it seems that if you want more accurate results, then play with your LocationRequest settings. Create a test app that allows you to change these settings dynamically. I have found that in a foreground app, Interval=1000 and FastestInterval=500, produces best-ish results. Also smallest displacement of about 20m. In either case, and for whatever reasons, changing these parameters changes the accuracy of the location returned in the Callback.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the type of location permission you're setting in your Manifest.

You have 2 available:

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION - This will allow you to access an approximate location

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION - This one will allow you to access a precise one, which I believe is what you want in your case.

Comment: Yes, I do have both the permissions added in the Manifest file.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION? There's no need to add both and if you want your location to be as precise as possible, I would only add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.